# Computing Pi in Java

Tags: java, variable-assignment, scientific-computing, pi

This weeks assignment in programming is to compute Pi in java using this as the basis for the assignment:

> 1. (for 80% of the marks):
>      USING A WHILE OR A DO-WHILE LOOP write a program to compute PI using the following equation:
>      PI = 3 + 4/(2*3*4) - 4/(4*5*6) + 4/(6*7*8) - 4/(8*9*10) + ...
>      Allow the user to specify the number of terms (5 terms are shown) to use in the computation.
>      Each time around the loop only one extra term should be added to the estimate for PI.
> 2. (for 20% of the marks):
>      Alter your solution from part one so that the user is 
>      allowed to specify the precision required between 1 and 8 digits 
>      (i.e. the number of digits which are correct; e.g. to 5 digits PI is 3.14159), 
>      rather than the number of terms.  The condition on the loop should be altered so that it 
>      continues until the required precision is obtained.  Note that you need only submit this 
>      second version of the program (assuming you have it working).

I'm only able to use the above method to compute Pi, as thats what the lecturer wants. Ive got this so far, although the code keeps giving me the same wrong answer for every even number and a different wrong answer for each odd number. Im still on part one as i havent got the right answer yet to be able to progress onto part 2.

All help would be great, as the program needs to be submitted by tueday.
Thanks in advance!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ComputePI {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.print( "Please enter the amount of decimal "
                + "digits of PI, you would like to set it too");
        Scanner termScan = new Scanner( System.in );
        int term = termScan.nextInt();
        termScan.close();
        double pi = 3.0;
        int loopCount = 2;
        int number = 2;


            while ( loopCount <= term )
            {
                if (loopCount % 2 == 0)
                {
                    pi = pi + ( 4.0/ ((number) * (number+1) * (number+2)) );
                }
                else 
                {
                    pi = pi - ( 4.0 / ((number) * (number+1) * (number+2)) );
                }

                number = number + 2;

                loopCount++;
            }

        System.out.print( "The Value of Pi in " + term +
                " terms is equal to " + pi);
    }

}
```

Comment: It seems to me you're adding an extra 2 on the negative term that is not needed; also, you can simplify your code ; first, if you have numberOne, you can get numberTwo and numberThree (just add 1 or 2) so you can have fewer variables; also, you can start your loopCount at 2, and avoid one if

Comment: ah i see that, yeah theyre just inefficiencies in the equation although changing them to what you have suggested(as i just did) had no change to the answer, which is my greater concern as i dont know how im not getting the correct answer?

Comment: **You will find a nice solution on the pi approach:** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70053809/9345726)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not going to give you code (you can figure it out for yourself, I'm certain), but I'll give you the location for where to look for the problem.

In the negative terms, you are adding `2` to each number multiplied together. However, you are adding `2` to each number in every iteration of the loop: the `numberXXX + 2` part should probably just be `numberXXX`.

You are now also incrementing the `numberXXX` variables when `loopCount` is `1`. In fact, the `if (loopCount == 1)` part is unnecessary, since you already initialize `pi`. You should just remove the `if` block there and switch the `loopCount % 2 == X` blocks around.

I'll also give you general advice about things you might want to consider in your code.

1. You don't need constants like `4.0` to be in a variable. Just replace `fourConstant` with `4.0`.
2. You don't need to use an `else if` for the third block: if `loopCount % 2` is not `0` it is definitely `1`.
3. `loopCount` can only get integer values, so it should probably be an `int`. A `double` just consumes extra memory (this is not too problematic here, but may be in large programs) and can in some cases lead to errors (too large numbers may cause rounding errors).
4. You don't need three variables for `numberOne`, `numberTwo` and `numberThree`; they can always be represented as `numberOne`, `numberOne + 1` and `numberOne + 2`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, Ive edited the code to your suggestions and the answers are closer to being correct but they are still wrong? Any other suggestions?

Comment: I keep getting 3.166666666665 for all even numbers, and a random 3.1XXXXXXXXXXXX digit for every odd number, they are getting closer to pi but they arent correct, and for every number higher than 8 it just returns 3.1666666666665 ?

Comment: @GregPenrose Can you post your new code to [pastebin](http://pastebin.com) so I can take a look at it?

Comment: It seems like you didn't remove the unnecessary `+ 2`  from each number.

Comment: i noticed that too, i just changed it before you commented actually, and it works, god i'm such an idiot, now to just start working on the second part, thanks for the help!

Comment: The program is returning the correct approximation for Pi but only up until 400 terms, after that the approximation starts to grow away from Pi although looking at the equation it should be exponential and not eventually start to level out, any chance you'd take a look at the code and see why? sorry about all the hassle, but thanks a lot!

http://pastebin.com/R2Dvx9im

Comment: This is about a whole different phenomenon. After ~400 terms, the values of the terms begin to lose accuracy. A `double` is only able to store 64 bits of data, split to 1 bit for the sign, 11 for the exponent and 52 for the significand. According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_double-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary64), this leads to a maximum precision of 15–17 significant decimal digits. If you need more, you can consider using a `BigDecimal`.

Answer (score 0):

You are incrementing the variables numerOne,numberTwo,numberThree in case the loopCount = 1. In this case you should just continue the loop without incrementing this variables. So change this:

```
if (loopCount == 1 )
{
    pi = 3.0;
}
```

in:

```
if (loopCount == 1 )
{
    pi = 3.0;
    loopCount++;
    continue;
}
```

And change this:

```
pi = pi - ( fourConstant / ((numberOne+2)*(numberTwo+2)*(numberThree+2)));
```

into:

```
pi = pi - ( fourConstant / ((numberOne)*(numberTwo)*(numberThree)));
```

Or you could just initialize loop count to 2 and remove the first if.

Additionally it would be better is loopCount and term were integer variables instead of Double since they are going to hold only integer values.